# Is there any way to implement Localization Internalization in CXF using Spring ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: web-services, spring, localization, internationalization, cxf

I have been searching for a Spring based configuration approach, to support Localization/Internationalization in my Rest based application developed in Apache CXF. I need to localize the Exception messages, responses of my APIs and other informational messages as per the Language user opts for. The Locale information will come in the Request Header "Accept-Language" parameter.

In Spring MVC, there is a predefined way which support Localization & is very useful in dynamically loading corresponding properties file from class-path based on a request parameter set for language.

```
Spring MVC uses 
ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource, 
LocaleChangeInterceptor, 
DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping to configure Localization.
```

But I am not able to find a similar way that can be used in CXF Restful web services.

Can anyone please put some light in it.

Thanks

Rahul